# PayPal IPN received but payment not added to order

Tags: paypal, ipn

We received a PayPal payment this morning where the transaction was not added to the order in Magento (payment still shows as pending).

I checked the IPN history on the PayPal site and it shows that the IPN was sent successfully and received a response code 200 from our website. This suggests to me that the problem was not on PayPal's end.

I have checked through our `access_log` and `system.log` files but there is nothing noteworthy in either of those files at the time of the IPN. The `access_log` shows:

```
access_log:173.0.81.1 - - [07/Sep/2015:09:46:52 +0000] "POST /paypal/ipn/ HTTP/1.0" 200 509 "-" "PayPal IPN ( https://www.paypal.com/ipn )"
```

Other PayPal payments have been received today and payment details are being added correctly.

We are running Magento CE 1.7.0.2 and are using PayPal Website Payments Standard.

Can anyone suggest how to identify what could cause this payment to not be applied to the order properly?

Comment: Have you looked at [IPN certificate changes](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82713/what-actions-are-necessary-for-paypals-announced-certificate-changes)?

Comment: Yes and we are compatible. However, we are using _Website Payments Standard_ and according to the PayPal article it says: `Upgrading is not required if you are using Website Payments Standard (the “Buy Now” buttons), or Payflow webapps only.`

We are receiving PayPal payments OK and just a single payment failed as per the original question.